# How to measure a curve on a spinning circle?

Tags: geometry

Picture a circle lying flat on the ground.  Say it's 5 meters in diameter.  There are two people standing on the circle: one in the center and one on the edge.  The circle is spinning at some speed, let's say 10km/h.

If the person in the center throws a ball to the person on the edge, that ball would have to move in a curved line relative to the circle.

My question: How could this path be described mathematically?  I've tagged this question "geometry" but there might be another way of doing it that makes more sense so all answers welcome.

Comment: Assuming the ball has constant velocity I believe the path will be an Archimedean spiral. You can see this more easily by really ramping up the spinning motion then asking how the path has to change when you do. You can see what's happening on potter's wheel by starting at the center and scoring the clay in a line outwards while it spins at a constant velocity. Naturally polar coordinately are useful here.

Comment: @CyclotomicField ahh...like this?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral

If you type that as an answer including the r = a + b * θ equation the points are yours!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the ball has constant velocity the path will be an [Archimedean spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral). You can see this more easily by really ramping up the spinning motion then asking how the path has to change when you do. You can see what's happening on potter's wheel by starting at the center and scoring the clay in a line outwards while it spins at a constant velocity.

Polar coordinates are useful here and we can represent the curve as $r=a+b\theta$.